# unable to run jmx file in docker

Tags: docker, jmx

Connected server from windows machine using cygwin

Created one docker file in server

```
[root@serverhost uname]# touch Dockerfile

[root@serverhost uname]# vi Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
#1
FROM artifactory.xxx.net/java:8.212.0.1557388225_openjdk_74e62a71
#2
LABEL maintainer="xxx@domain.com"
# 3
ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.2"

# 4
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV MIRROR_HOST http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/apache/jmeter
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL ${MIRROR_HOST}/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/

# 5
RUN    apk update \
        && apk upgrade \
        && apk add ca-certificates \
        && update-ca-certificates \
            && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
            && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime \
            && echo "Europe/Rome" >  /etc/timezone \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
        && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
        && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
        && mkdir -p /opt  \
        && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
        && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

# 6
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-dummy/0.2/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter/0.5/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar

# 7
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

# 8
COPY launch.sh /

#9
WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}

#10
ENTRYPOINT ["/launch.sh"]
```

Created launch.sh file in same folder where docker is created

```
[root@serverhost uname]# touch launch.sh

[root@serverhost uname]# vi launch.sh
```

launch.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
freeMem=`awk '/MemFree/ { print int($2/1024) }' /proc/meminfo`
s=$(($freeMem/10*8))
x=$(($freeMem/10*8))
n=$(($freeMem/10*2))
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmn${n}m -Xms${s}m -Xmx${x}m"

echo "START Running Jmeter on `date`"
echo "JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS}"
echo "jmeter args=$@"

# Keep entrypoint simple: we must pass the standard JMeter arguments
jmeter $@
echo "END Running Jmeter on `date`"
```

Built the docker and tagged it

```
[root@serverhost uname]# docker build .

[root@serverhost uname]# docker tag 090847728937 jmautomation:1.0
```

exit from server and copied my local jmx file folder to server

```
uname@QINDW191 /cygdrive/c/jmeter/$ scp -r jmeterscript uname@serverhost:~/

[uname@serverhost~]$ ls -lrt

total 12

-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   1678 Nov 26 10:29 Dockerfile

-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root    331 Nov 26 11:00 launch.sh

drwxrwx---. 2 uname uname 4096 Nov 28 09:17 jmeterscript
```

Running jmx file in docker by copying folder to docker mnt/jmeter folder and running jmx file from there:

```
[root@serverhost uname]# docker run -v /home/uname/jmeterscript:/mnt/jmeter jmautomation:1.0 -n -Jenv=devint  -t /mnt/jmeter/api_regression.jmx -l /mnt/jmeter/result.xml

[root@serverhost uname]# docker run --volume "/home/uname/jmeterscript":/mnt/jmeter jmautomation:1.0 -n -Jenv=devint  -t /mnt/jmeter/api_regression.jmx -l /mnt/jmeter/result.xml

[root@serverhost uname]# docker run --volume "/home/uname/jmeterscript":/mnt/jmeter jmautomation:1.0 -n -Jenv="devint"  -t /mnt/jmeter/api_regression.jmx -l /mnt/jmeter/result.xml

[root@serverhost uname]# docker run --volume "/home/uname/jmeterscript":/mnt jmautomation:1.0 -n -Jenv=devint  -t /mnt/api_regression.jmx -l /mnt/result.xml
```

Tried to run with all above commands every time I am facing below error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"-n\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Can anyone please help me what I am missing?

Comment: Can you check that you actually have the image you're expecting?  You can use `docker build -t jmautomation:1.0 .` to combine the "build" and "tag" steps.  (It's acting like the `ENTRYPOINT` declaration is missing, or else the script isn't actually running `meter` like you show.)

Comment: Here, I have given Entry point as launch.sh, and my jmx file is running in my machine from command prompt successfully, it is only problem while running jmx file in docker. If anyone running jmx files on docker, please share me your dockerfile